# Netlogo turtles move and angle

Tags: netlogo

I want to move my turtles and I want that they don't go out of my field.
For example, If turtles 1 have to attack the goal that is in the right place of the screen, I don't want that the turtles 1 that is in the left side go out from the field and reappear on the right side(and viceversa).
I initial found a possibile solution by set the goal position, and use :

```
 facexy-nowrap goal-xcor goal-ycor
```

But It doesn't help me because I use this command only for attack behavior, and I prefer to not use it...
So there is another solution? like using field lines?

Comment: Can you turn world wrapping off in the settings, or are you constrained to leaving that turned on?

Comment: sorry for the question but what do you mean with "turn world wrapping off"? I am very new with netlogo

Comment: No problem! Have a look at the [Topology section](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#topology) of the user manual for more details, but in short- although the default NetLogo world is a Torus you can turn that off so that the world has hard boundaries in the vertical, horizontal, or both directions. Click "Settings" on the interface tab and then tick or untick the "World Wraps Horizontally" or "World Wraps Vertically"  buttons to modify those settings.

Comment: Thank you! Now it works! =) If your reply with this comment I will use it like the correct answer =)

Comment: and then just use `facexy` instead of `facexy-nowrap`